# remove child using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

What I have:

```
<div class="draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" name="text" id="created_at" style="opacity: 1;"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>created_at</div>
```

What I need:

```
<div class="draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" name="text" id="created_at" style="opacity: 1;">created_at</div>
```

What I tried:

```
ui.draggable.clone().find("i").remove();
```

This removing i tag as well as text next to it.

**EDIT:**

After dropping into container i want to remove i from that div tag.

Comment: `$('.fa-globe').remove();`

Comment: I will have different icons for different divs. all are dynamically generated.

Comment: why are you cloning before removing?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to accomplish. Can you please elaborate on the goal of your code?

Comment: So you want to delete all icons?

Comment: They all are draggable fields so i need them at draggable as well as in dropped container. @Pete

Comment: After dropping into container i want to remove i from that div tag. @WouterBouwman

Comment: just added an example snippet with the drag drop demo see if that what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that would be a problem see below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#remove").click(function() {
    $('.ui-draggable >i.fa').remove();
  });

  $(".area-drop").droppable({
    accept: ".drag-item",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      let draggable = $(ui.draggable[0]);
      let draggableClone = draggable.clone();
      $(this).append(draggableClone);
      draggable.find('i.fa').remove();
    }
  });

  $(".drag-item").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.area-drop {
  border: 1px dashed #000;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}

i.fa {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.drag-item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.drag-item:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 15px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<p>Drag icons to the DROP ZONE to filter out icons</p>


<div class="drag-item" name="text" id="created_at"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>created_at</div>
<div class="drag-item" name="text" id="created_at"><i class="fa fa-map" aria-hidden="true"></i>updated_at</div>
<div class="drag-item" name="text" id="created_at"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>created_at</div>
<div class="drag-item" name="text" id="created_at"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>created_at</div>

<div class="area-drop">
  DROP ZONE
</div>
```

Comment: This $('.ui-draggable >i.fa').remove(); removing all icons on page. I need it for particular div element which is droppable.

Comment: check now i have updated with multiple icons in the snippet , it will remove only the dragged item's icon @Praveen

Comment: `$(ui.draggable[0]);` get the dragged item object only and you can do whatever you want to , it wont effect other draggable items or `fontawesome` icons

Comment: $(ui.draggable[0]); worked for me although if we want to append the div to .area-drop div use : let draggable = $(ui.draggable[0]);
 draggable.find('i.fa').remove();
draggable.clone().appendTo($(this));

Comment: sorry i couldnt get your last part what are you trying to say here **if we want to append the div to . .area-drop div use : let draggable = $(ui.draggable[0]); draggable.find('i.fa').remove();**

Comment: <div class="drag-item" name="text" id="created_at"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>created_at</div> to drop into DROP ZONE.

Comment: ahh ok you want the draggable item to be appended to the drop zone div once it is dropped , isnt it?

Comment: @Praveen i just updated the answer see if that is what you are trying to achieve, you can format the css yourself, i didnt gave that a go but you can append the draggable along with the icon to the DROP ZONE now

Answer (score 0):

You can do `jQuery('.draggable i').remove();` and the text will remain.

Answer (score 0):

If **id** of the parent is fixed then you can do something like that:-

```
var elToRemove = $("#created_at").find('i');
if(elToRemove.length){
     elToRemove.remove();
}
```